# BizTalk TypePolling receive port silently fails

Tags: biztalk

I've created a SQL stored procedure to use with a TypedPolling receive port.
It silently fails and I have no clue why.
It posts no messages and does not produce errors in the event log.

I used the tutorial [here](https://www.tallan.com/blog/2014/12/23/typed-polling-with-wcf-adapters/) to create the schema and receive port:

[image: Receive location configuration]

I have the sql server profiler connected when I enable the receive location:
[image: SQL Profile Trace]

The SPROC works correctly when executed manually and the execution time matches the time the profile shows. I've turned on "Enable Routing for failed messages" and created a send port with a filter
matching the MessageType.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your polledDataAvailableStatement `SELECT`, that means it will execute every time.   Did you make any changes to your stored procedure after you generated the schema?  If so you may need to do that again.

Comment: Normally when Adapter fails to receive messages or fails to map messages to schema, it logs a warning in event viewer log. It may not suspend anything. Some basic pointers: you may want to double check your SP results. look at your timeouts which are unusually high for some reason. Check yr connection string for environment

Comment: @Dijkgraaf When the time is within the service window it will run at the start. The poll interval is longer than the service window so it runs once each time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: "Patience."  There was nothing wrong with the setup.

I waited several minutes for results and when nothing happened I disabled the port.  Disabling the port aborts the process. It took more than the minutes I waited after the SPROC completed for a message to be returned.